# C programming - how to use a While loop for save user's values in an array

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop

I'm trying to create an array from user's input and then I'll analyze it and say if it is a symmetric array or not.

But I've already a problem in my while loop and I can't understand where is the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int array[]         = {};
    int i               = 0;
    int user            = 0;
    int k               = 0;
    int size_array      = 0;
    int j               = 0;


    printf("Write some numbers, -1 to end \n");

    while(user != -1){
        printf("k = %d\n", k);
        scanf("%d", &user);
        array[i] = user;

        i = i+1;
        k = k+1;
    }

    size_array = k;
    printf("nb of entries = %d\n", size_array);

    for (j = 0; j < size_array; j++){
        printf("%d",array[j]);
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

This is the output :

```
Write some numbers, -1 to end
k = 0
1
k = 1
1
k = 2
1
k = 2
1
k = 3
1
k = 2
2
k = 3
2
k = 4
2
k = 5
2
k = 6
2
k = 7
2
k = 8
-1
nb of entries = 9
919026867601999609396268686841986531
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 10.320 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Where's the problem???
Sorry for multiple variables (j k i) but I thought there was an interference using the same variable for different loops...

Comment: This shouldn't even compile. Your compiler might be mis-configured. I case you are using gcc, you have to specify `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` to prevent it from being stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is

```
int array[]         = {};
```

which is a basically a zero-sized array and in C, arrays cannot be *re-sized*.

For this very reason, every access to `array[i]` in your code is an invalid memory access which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You have to either provide the size of supply a longer initializer list to have a meaningful size of the array to make it *usable*.

Comment: "supply a longer initializer list to have a meaningful size of the array to make it usable." Can you please provide me an example?

Comment: @Jurafsky `int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5};` is a simple and  good example.

Comment: but the problem is that in my case the user has to write down the numbers... So when I initialize the array I don't know neither size nor values

Comment: You need to a) provide either exact or more elements than You need b) consider using dynamic arrays - user defined size arrays (http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/416/)

Comment: @Jurafsky You can solve that problem with dynamic memory allocation. But forget about that for now, focus on learning how arrays work (and then pointers).

Comment: @Jurafsky in case of a dynamic input, fixed size arrays are not the best solution. YOu have to use dynamic memory allocation and re-allocation for the required memory, but that's the next chapter. As you now, you can start with a fixed size array and limit the number of user inputs (say, 100 or 1000), that should work fine.